# is there a way to get the ips of all the services available in a network using ssdp?

Tags: java, ssdp

I am trying to create a java program making use of SSDP to get the list of IP's of the systems connected to a server. Is it possible? If so can anyone tell me the method? Because as per I read they have just mentioned we can find the particular service over the network not all the services.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The idea of "IPs being connected to a server" doesn't really match what happens in SSDP, but you can search for all services and devices that advertize over SSDP in a given local network: use the search target `ssdp:all` instead of a specific service type string when you send your M-SEARCH message.

If you are thinking of building this from scratch, I suggest using a UPnP (or SSDP) library/framework: it'll probably make life easier.